# Select Customer whose is inactive

Tags: oracle

I am working on query :

```
Table 1-
Id Customer status
------------------
1   AB      Active
2   AB      Inactive
1   BC      Inactive
2   BC      Inactive
```

Output

```
------
Customer
BC
```

As customer status is inactive in all the IDs need to select only that customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this uses aggregation by customer:

```sql
SELECT Customer
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status <> 'Inactive' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: It will give output as - customer- BC AB

Comment: No it won't.  Either you didn't run my actual answer, or your data is something other than what you posted above.

Comment: I want to select only those customers who is inactive in both ID 1 and 2 which is Customer 'BC'. Your above query will select 'AB' customer also

Comment: I have given a valid answer, which you did not test.

Comment: Sorry in my part.. it is working now.. i was selecting all three columns so i didn't got that answer. Thank you for your help.